# How to integrate $(x-1)^4/(x^2 )$?

Tags: integration

How to integrate $\frac {(x-1)^4} {x^2 }$ ?

I really tried hard but don't know how to start please guide me to just start

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

$(x-1)^4=x^4-4x^3+6x^2-4x+1$, so
$$
\frac{(x-1)^4}{x^2}=x^2-4x+6-\frac{4}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}
$$
Can you go on?

Comment: yes , I can go now , thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** This is a low-degree polynomial divided by a monomial. Just expand it and divide. So you have to integrate

$$\int \frac{x^4 - 4x^3 + 6x^2 - 4x +1}{x^2}dx$$
$$=\int\left(x^2 - 4x + 6 -\frac4x + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: thanks , I solved , 〖1/3 x〗^3-2x^2+6x-4 ln⁡(x)-1/x

Comment: Okay, good. You need to work on your MathJax markup for this site. I think you got it right -- hard to read what you meant. I think you are saying $\frac13x^3 -2x^2 + 6x -4\ln x -\frac1{x^2}$